# Trouble with an open QueueingNetworkProcess: Missing Performance measures

Tags: missing

I'm trying to create the following open network using Mathematica:

[image: Network]

First of all, I define the variables of this network, in this way:

```
g = {2, 2, 0, 0, 2};
p = {{0, 1/4, 0, 0, 3/4}, {0, 0, 1/3, 2/3, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
     0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 1/2, 0}};
m = {3, 3, 3, 3, 3};
c = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
```

Then, I execute the function QueueingNetworkProcess with those values:

```
NET = QueueingNetworkProcess[g, p, m, c];
```

I don't know why, but when I execute the QueueProperties function, sometimes Performance Measures outputs "Missing[NotAvailable]".

```
Table[QueueProperties[{NET, i}], {i, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

I want to get values for the Mean Time for a traffic going by 1-5-2-4. Theoretically I have to get the following, supposedly:

[image]

I think I'm doing well, but there's the problem of that Missing thing. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your queues' lengths diverge you'll get that kind of answer.
Consider the simpler:

```
γ = {3, 3}; μ = {1, 1};
r = {{0, 1/2}, {1/4, 0}};
c = {1, 1};
net = QueueingNetworkProcess[γ, r, μ, c];
Table[QueueProperties[{net, i}], {i, 1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

versus the same, but increasing the service rate:

```
μ = {10, 10};
net = QueueingNetworkProcess[γ, r, μ, c];
Table[QueueProperties[{net, i}], {i, 1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Your problem works if you set the service vector values greater than 4.

Comment: To be precise, the following vector will do: `m = {3, 17/4 + ϵ, 3, 55/12 + ϵ, 7/2 + ϵ};` for any ϵ>0

Comment: Thanks to both of you, it worked. I was getting obfuscated with that kind of error :)